# Prevent iCloud from downloading older app version

Tags: ios, app-store, icloud

I have uploaded a new version of my app which contains some DB (Used CoreData) changes (server side changes too). I have added new model so that the DB changes do not causes any crash.

Downloading the app freshly works fine. If an older version of the app is in cloud, then when i try to install the app (shows cloud icon), older version gets downloaded and casues a crash. Is there a way to prevent the iCloud from restoring/downloading the older verion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following steps solved my problem.

1. In itunes connect click on the app icon.
2. Select **'Rights and Pricing'**
3. Now select **'Manage iCloud settings for this app'**
4. Now **check** the versions that you don't want the users to download from iCloud.

Answer (score 4):

Let me credit @grgarside for his answer here -> https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254181/121124

**iTunes Connect → My Apps → app → App Store → Pricing & Availability → Last-Compatible Version Settings → Available Versions.**

is the new flow sequence, you are looking for.
I am writing this as a new answer, as the user interface has changed a lot as compared to the 2013 version.

here is the 2017 version

[image: itunesconnect last-compatible version settings]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't prevent users from using their own backups, and you shouldn't either. You've probably handled the update badly if your app crashes on restoring the version (possibly updating?). [Core data model versioning and migrating](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) is what you need when updating the core data model in the current app version and want to keep backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks. But I have already added a new versioning. Also there is some changes in the data from the server side, which is handled in new version. The same app works if we download the app freshly. After that even from the cloud works fine. The issue happens if there is an older version in the cloud.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'an older version in the cloud' ?